# URL rewrite using htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to get SEO friendly urls using htaccess rewrite rules. Please find them below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^brands brands.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^facebook/([0-9]+) facebook.php?fb_page_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^twitter/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) twitter.php?twitter_screen_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

I verified in my localhost all the link they are working fine in xampp environment. But when i hosted them in remote server with OS centos and virtualhost configuration for a subdomain.

My Original urls will be like below.

```
base_url/facebook.php/fb_page_name=7up+India

base_url/twitter.php/twitter_screen_name=7up+India
```

The rules are not working and giving internal server error like below.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
enter code here
```

So i verified in remote server with simple htaccess redirection rules like below one to main site. It worked perfectly. I am not able to find what went wrong.

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```

My Original URL format was this `http://example.com/facebook.php/fb_page_name=7up+India`
Calling URL format in pages was this `href='/facebook/7up+India'`
Final expecting url was this `http://example.com/facebook/7up+India`

Comment: Have you looked at the server error log, like the error says? It might contain valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^brands$ brands.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^facebook/([0-9]+)$ facebook.php?fb_page_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^twitter/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ twitter.php?twitter_screen_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

You missed to add `$`, which indicates the end of regular expression.

Comment: What is you page URL looks like?

Comment: My page url looking base_url/brands.php,base_url/facebook.php?fb_page_id=3343131343,base_url/twitter.php?twitter_screen_name=dhjhsdhsjadhs

Comment: are you sure that other configuration of Apache are correct? Try removing all code from `.htaccess` and check?

Comment: try commenting `Options +FollowSymLinks` , that could be a problem. Other rule seems fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64223/discussion-between-venkat-and-php-weblineindia).

Comment: I am not able to get GET parameters in server now.

Comment: PHP Weblineindia I am using your rewrite rules but not working chekc my original urls in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^brands brands.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+facebook\.php\?fb_page_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ facebook/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+twitter\.php\?twitter_screen_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ twitter/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^facebook/([^/]+)/?$ facebook.php?fb_page_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^twitter/([^/]+)/?$ twitter.php?twitter_screen_name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: please check my original url formats in the question or below here.
base_url/facebook.php/fb_page_name=7up+India

base_url/twitter.php/twitter_screen_name=7up+India

Comment: I am getting error as this in error log of apache Undefined index: fb_page_id

Comment: this is the way i am gathering GET parameters in respective pages
preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i', '', urldecode($_GET['fb_page_name']));

preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i', '', urldecode($_GET['twitter_screen_name']));

Comment: I updated all the url formats at the end of question

Comment: yeah i updated with your rules and tried not working

Comment: [ok join this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64223/discussion-between-venkat-and-php-weblineindia)

Comment: Options MultiViews must be disabled to make it work. You need to enable use of Options from server config by using Options All in it. I lost my internet connection again.

Comment: hey Anubhav I am able to resolve the issue but i am facing issue while extracting get parameter like i am getting only half of the string. I am using this regex to extract a string which had underscore in url parameter.
preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i', '', urldecode($_GET['twitter_screen_name']));

Comment: No i am not getting anything with that.

Comment: If `$_GET['twitter_screen_name'])` is not giving you anything then how come half of the string???

Comment: As per my understanding the GET parameter won't give any out put when you rewrite the url using htaccess unless you use preg_replace so i am using it. So my string was abh_pune output was giving abh only

Comment: Then clear your understanding first. If `$_GET['twitter_screen_name'])` is empty then `preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i', '', urldecode($_GET['twitter_screen_name']));` will ALSO NOT work. And sorry I cannot comment endlessly like this. Read little bit about `preg_replace` and use of `$_GET` then attempt to solve this.

Comment: You're mistaken again. Query string is used as `$_GET` with underscore.